# Reduce data in SQL table created due to a bug

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Due to a software bug that was unfortunately not obvious enough in the develop environment to be recognized, it happened that we created massive loads of SQL records we do not actually need. The records do not harm data integrity or anything else, but they are simply unnecessary.

We are looking at a database schema like the following:

```
entity_static (just some static data that won't change):

id | val1 | val2 | val3
-----------------------
1  | 50   | 183  | 93
2  | 60   | 823  | 123


entity_dynamic (some dynamic data we need a historical record of):

id | entity_static_id | val1 | val2 | valid_from          | valid_to
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1                | 50   | 75   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59
2  | 1                | 50   | 75   | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2018-01-01 01:59:59
3  | 1                | 50   | 75   | 2018-01-01 02:00:00 | 2018-01-01 02:59:59
4  | 1                | 50   | 75   | 2018-01-01 03:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59
5  | 2                | 60   | 75   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59
6  | 2                | 60   | 75   | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2018-01-01 01:59:59
7  | 2                | 60   | 75   | 2018-01-01 02:00:00 | 2018-01-01 02:59:59
8  | 2                | 60   | 75   | 2018-01-01 03:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59
```

There are some more columns besides `val1` and `val2`, this is just an example.

The `entity_dynamic` table describes what parameters were valid for a given period of time. It is **not** a recording for a certain point in time (like sensor data).

Therefor all equal records could easily be aggregated into one record like the following:

```
id | entity_static_id | val1 | val2 | valid_from          | valid_to
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1                | 50   | 75   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59
5  | 2                | 60   | 75   | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59
```

It is possible that the data in the `valid_to` column is `NULL`.

My question is now, with what query am I able to aggregate similar records with consecutive validity ranges into one record. Grouping should be done by the foreign key on `entity_static_id`.

Comment: Look towards for example ROW_NUMBER() to find duplicate values that can then be handled.

Comment: Finding the duplicate records is not the issue, it can be achieved easily by using a sub-query that counts similar records. I have issues with determing which records I can aggregate (due to their chronical order) and how I can aggregate the.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with entity_dynamic  as
(
select
*
from 
(values
('1','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 00:59:59')
,('2','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 01:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 01:59:59')
,('3','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 02:59:59')
,('4','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 03:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 03:59:59')
,('5','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 00:59:59')
,('6','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 01:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 01:59:59')
,('7','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 02:59:59')
,('8','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 03:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 03:59:59')
,('9','1','60','75',' 2018-01-01 04:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 04:59:59')
,('10','1','60','75',' 2018-01-01 05:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 05:59:59')
,('11','2','70','75',' 2018-01-01 04:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 04:59:59')
,('12','2','70','75',' 2018-01-01 05:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 05:59:59')
,('13','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 06:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 06:59:59')
)
 a(id , entity_static_id , val1 , val2 , valid_from , valid_to)
 )
 ,
```

First add rownumbers for the unique combinations of val1 and val2 for each entity_static_id (unique group), add a row number for entity_static_id. Order by valid_from descending

```
 step1 as
 (
 select 
 id , entity_static_id , val1 , val2 , valid_from , valid_to
 ,row_number() over (partition by entity_static_id,val1,val2 order by valid_from) valrn
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by entity_static_id order by valid_from desc) rn

 from entity_dynamic 
)
```

This gives:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id|entity_static_id|val1|val2|valid_from           |valid_to            |unique_group|rn|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|10|1               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 05:00:00 | 2018-01-01 05:59:59|2           |1 |
|9 |1               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 04:00:00 | 2018-01-01 04:59:59|1           |2 |
|4 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 03:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59|4           |3 |
|3 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 02:00:00 | 2018-01-01 02:59:59|3           |4 |
|2 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2018-01-01 01:59:59|2           |5 |
|1 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59|1           |6 |
|13|2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 06:00:00 | 2018-01-01 06:59:59|5           |1 |
|12|2               |70  |75  | 2018-01-01 05:00:00 | 2018-01-01 05:59:59|2           |2 |
|11|2               |70  |75  | 2018-01-01 04:00:00 | 2018-01-01 04:59:59|1           |3 |
|8 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 03:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59|4           |4 |
|7 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 02:00:00 | 2018-01-01 02:59:59|3           |5 |
|6 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2018-01-01 01:59:59|2           |6 |
|5 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59|1           |7 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Step2 is to add the rownumber for each unique group and the overall row num, since the last is descending, row with equal values following each other vil have the same sum, called tar in this example

```
,step2 as
(
select
*
,unique_group+rn tar
from step1
)
```

Step 2 gives:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id|entity_static_id|val1|val2|valid_from           |valid_to            |unique_group|rn|tar|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|10|1               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 05:00:00 | 2018-01-01 05:59:59|2           |1 |3  |
|9 |1               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 04:00:00 | 2018-01-01 04:59:59|1           |2 |3  |
|4 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 03:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59|4           |3 |7  |
|3 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 02:00:00 | 2018-01-01 02:59:59|3           |4 |7  |
|2 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2018-01-01 01:59:59|2           |5 |7  |
|1 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59|1           |6 |7  |
|13|2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 06:00:00 | 2018-01-01 06:59:59|5           |1 |6  |
|12|2               |70  |75  | 2018-01-01 05:00:00 | 2018-01-01 05:59:59|2           |2 |4  |
|11|2               |70  |75  | 2018-01-01 04:00:00 | 2018-01-01 04:59:59|1           |3 |4  |
|8 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 03:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59|4           |4 |8  |
|7 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 02:00:00 | 2018-01-01 02:59:59|3           |5 |8  |
|6 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2018-01-01 01:59:59|2           |6 |8  |
|5 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:59:59|1           |7 |8  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally, you can find the valid_from and vallid_to dates by using min and maxm and group by the correct values:

```
select
min(id) id
,entity_static_id
,val1
,val2
,min(valid_from) valid_from
,max(valid_to) valid_to
from step2
group by entity_static_id,val1
    ,val2   
    ,tar
order by entity_static_id,valid_from
```

In totality the code is:

```
with entity_dynamic  as
(
select
*
from 
(values
('1','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 00:59:59')
,('2','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 01:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 01:59:59')
,('3','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 02:59:59')
,('4','1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 03:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 03:59:59')
,('5','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 00:59:59')
,('6','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 01:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 01:59:59')
,('7','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 02:59:59')
,('8','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 03:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 03:59:59')
,('9','1','60','75',' 2018-01-01 04:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 04:59:59')
,('10','1','60','75',' 2018-01-01 05:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 05:59:59')
,('11','2','70','75',' 2018-01-01 04:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 04:59:59')
,('12','2','70','75',' 2018-01-01 05:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 05:59:59')
,('13','2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 06:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 06:59:59')
)
 a(id , entity_static_id , val1 , val2 , valid_from , valid_to)
 )
 ,step1 as
 (
 select 
 id , entity_static_id , val1 , val2 , valid_from , valid_to
 ,row_number() over (partition by entity_static_id,val1,val2 order by valid_from) unique_group
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by entity_static_id order by valid_from desc) rn

 from entity_dynamic 
)
,step2 as
(
select
*
,dense_rank() over (partition by entity_static_id order by unique_group) f
,unique_group+rn tar
from step1
)
select
min(id) id
,entity_static_id
,val1
,val2
,min(valid_from) valid_from
,max(valid_to) valid_to
from step2
group by entity_static_id,val1
    ,val2   
    ,tar
order by entity_static_id,valid_from
```

The result is

```
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id|entity_static_id|val1|val2|valid_from           |valid_to            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1 |1               |50  |75  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59|
|10|1               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 04:00:00 | 2018-01-01 05:59:59|
|5 |2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 03:59:59|
|11|2               |70  |75  | 2018-01-01 04:00:00 | 2018-01-01 05:59:59|
|13|2               |60  |75  | 2018-01-01 06:00:00 | 2018-01-01 06:59:59|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'll have an in-depth look at this shortly. For now it looks like it is what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, it worked out quite well. As I couldn't really figure out how to properly deal with `NULL` values for the `valid_to` column, I did aggregate only records without `NULL` values and applied a `UNION` afterwards. In total it shrunk the table by about 99,73% (record count), which is totally plausible considering the average number of duplicates was nearly 1k per record. :)

Answer (score 1):

If group is defined by entity_dynamic then this should be all you need

```
with entity_dynamic  as
( select *
  from (values ('1' ,'1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 00:59:59')
              ,('2' ,'1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 01:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 01:59:59')
              ,('3' ,'1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 02:59:59')
              ,('4' ,'1','50','75',' 2018-01-01 03:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 03:59:59')
              ,('5' ,'2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 00:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 00:59:59')
              ,('6' ,'2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 01:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 01:59:59')
              ,('7' ,'2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 02:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 02:59:59')
              ,('8' ,'2','60','75',' 2018-01-01 03:00:00 ',' 2018-01-01 03:59:59')
       ) a(id , entity_static_id , val1 , val2 , valid_from , valid_to) 
) 
, entity_dynamicPlus as 
( select * 
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by entity_static_id order by valid_to asc ) as rnA 
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by entity_static_id order by valid_to desc) as rnD 
   from entity_dynamic 
) 
select eStart.id, eStart.entity_static_id, eStart.val1, eStart.val2, eStart.valid_from, eEnd.valid_to 
     , eEnd.valid_to 
from entity_dynamicPlus as eStart 
join entity_dynamicPlus as eEnd 
  on eStart.entity_static_id = eEnd.entity_static_id 
 and eStart.rnA = 1 
 and eEnd.rnD   = 1
order by eStart.entity_static_id
```